# HOW TO USE PURGE COMMAND INSIDE ON_MESSAGE

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I found a purge command, but it doesn't work for me because I use `client = discord.Client(command_prefix = '$', description = ' ')` and not `client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '$')` And I use a lot of commands in

```
@client.event 
async def on_message(message):
```

so I wanted to use purge command in `on_message` too. Thanks!

Purge command:

```
@client.command()
async def clear(ctx, amount = 5):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit = amount)
```

Comment: An `on_message` event is not really worth it. You can do something like: `if message.content.startswith("clear"):`

Comment: What can I use instead of `@client.command()` ?

Comment: Why would you want to use something else?

Comment: because I have a different client which has no attribute commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted my first answer as I saw I could improve, I ended up finding you can do

```py
ctx = await client.get_context(message)
split = message.content.split()
if split[0] == "$clear": #Checking if the message is the clear command, you can also use message.content.tolower().startswith("$clear"):
    if len(split) == 2:
        num = 0
        try:
            num = int(split[1]) #checking if the second param <amount> is an int
        except ValueError:
            await message.channel.send("<amount> in $clear <amount> must be a number")
            return
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit = num)
    else:
        await message.channel.send("Please enter the command as $clear <amount>")
```

It works fine for me. Also client has to be

```
client = commands.Bot(params)
```

Comment: Great! Thanks! I appreciate your help!

Comment: You are welcome! It never even occurred to me I can do this until I saw your question! So in a way you also helped me with my bot!

Answer (score 1):

You have to do the same if-Statement as you're already doing it for other commands in the on_message event. Due to you're using it in an on_message event, you're not really able to set an amount on using the command, so you've to predefine it.

Define the amount and define a channel to purge in.
You can get the channel by using `discord.Client.get_channel` or by choosing the channel the message has been sent to `message.channel`.

Comment: and how do i get the ammount

Comment: You have to define the amount by yourself using `amount = 15` for example.